# Scientific notation last digits omitted as zeros when write.csv

Tags: r

I have a lot of long numbers and r reads them as scientific notation. But when I `write.csv`, the scientific notation becomes an incorrect number with a bunch of zeros following. For example, `3.894e+13` will become `38944400000000` after the `write.csv.`

I have exact numbers in the place where the zeros are.
How do I keep the exact number when exporting a data file?

[**update**]:
(1) The problem is because when I save as csv in excel, it loses digits of long numbers. It is an excel bug  and I use excel 2016.

(2) when the above problem occurred, I tired to set `options(scipen=999)`. When I summarize the data, the summary statistics are omitted always in this file. I tried other files, it (`summary`) works without losing precision. When I do print the numbers, it is correct, only the summary statistics are omitted after I set options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the the `scipen` option to be a large enough number before writing the csv file is one way to make it work:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1232939143546532)
options(scipen = 30)
write.csv(df, "test.cv")
```

This gives the following:

```
"","x"
"1",1232939143546532
```

Comment: Could also do `write.csv(format(df, digits = 22), quote = FALSE)` and not have to change any options.